# Write unit test for the SOAP client

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, junit

I have a SOAP client provided below:

```
@Component
public class Sales2Client extends XWebserviceClient {
    
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sales2Client.class);
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sales2Template")
    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;
    
    public Sales2ObjectFactory factory;
    private DateTimeConverter dateTimeConverter;
    
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where does the NPE happen?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli sorry I have this error ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext```

Comment: That means that you have two implementations of the sam Interface sales2Client. Why is BrinkWebserviceClient  a Spring Bean?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli not sure if I understand it. I added the relevant code for the question and  there are not 2 implementation. 

Why is BrinkWebserviceClient a Spring Bean > good question. I will see if I can get rid of this component.

Comment: You are correct, we dont need the component for the BrinkWebserviceClient and remove it. I still have the same error though.

Comment: It complains about brinkSales2Client is this a bean as well?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yeah, this is a config class that is provided in the undated question. the BrinkWebserviceConfig is the base config class.

Comment: So that's the problem You have two componentes of Typ Sales2Client and Mockito does not know which to mock. Which one should be mocked?

Comment: This @MockBean. private Sales2Client sales2Client;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have two components of the same type you have to qualify the name:

```
@MockBean(name = "sales2Client")
private Sales2Client sales2Client;
```